# Where should I go to ask a question about Wicca?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I had a question I wanted to pose to [Pagans and Wiccans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicca), asking if they believe love spells are ethical and why.

Scrolling through the sites that SE has to offer, though, I realized that there isn't any "religion" Stack Exchange site, or any non-denominational religious Stack Exchange site. There are widely used Stack Exchange sites for [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com), [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com), [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com), [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com), and [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com).  However, there isn't any Stack Exchange site for any kind of Pagan religions.

*Is there anywhere where this question would be appropriate?*  I considered *[Mythology/Folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com)* and *[Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com)*, but I don't think my question belongs either places.

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but maybe https://mythology.stackexchange.com/ might be appropriate.

Comment: Christianity has a pagan tag https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagan

Comment: Philosophy has an ethics tag but you would probably need to word your question carefully to post it there. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics

Comment: Also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ might be appropriate to discuss ethics, but that also may need to have a serious scientific background regarding those _love spells_ and if they work in the _real world_.

Comment: To start a proposal, do your [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80118/282094) first. Find somewhere to announce that's certain to bring in a lot of committed followers. Bask in your success.

Comment: I feel Skeptics may be a bit to.. skeptical for a "religion" question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A question like that really does need to be addressed to a group of Wiccans, or a minimum, neo-pagans (or people with an interest in neo-paganism) since most outside of those communities are unlikely to have a solid answer for you. Sadly we really don't have a site like that on the network yet.

In terms of an Area 51 an ideal proposal would be one for broad [Neo-Pagan traditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Paganism), New Age practices, and other re-constructionist religions to ensure enough subscription to get started. There is likely to be some quibbling between the groups but a big group is kind of needed. However, getting high subscription might be tricky since people don't necessary want to mix professional conduct (ex., StackOverflow) with their religion since they aren't exactly mainstream or accepted.

Comment: Even if you could get an exception to the rule about locating an outside community, I seriously doubt you can pull together sufficient support for it from existing SE participants.

Comment: You got six followers in 24 hours.  That's not enough to say if it was making good progress or not -- many proposals get an initial burst like that, then top out at 10-20 followers.

Comment: There has been at least one previous attempts to create a neo-pagan stack.  It failed due to lack of support - not enough questions, not enough votes. This presumably affected the decision to close the new proposal. (My recollection from that attempt was also that at least some of the questions covered things that are generally oathbound for Wiccans, which made me personally less inclined to participate in that stack.)

Answer (score 7):

There are two things to consider.  One is where the subject matter would be on-topic.  The other is where there is a collection of subject matter experts to provide an answer.  I'm not sure how many experts in Wicca there are on the Stack Exchange, and where they might congregate so there would be a pool of potential answerers viewing the question.

This is probably a subject where you would do better to find a dedicated forum.  For the heck of it, I put "wicca forum" into Google, and it turns out there are a bunch of dedicated sites.  With a lot of niche questions, it's easier to get an answer if you go to where the biggest concentration of subject matter experts are.

Answer (score 6):

If you start an Area 51 proposal for an "Other Religions" stack, I would support it!  It seems like religions here are grouped almost like the Dewey Decimal System, with 80 specific Christianity classifications, a few for Judaism, a few for the other ones you named above, and then "Other"

ok, I exaggerate slightly - here's the actual current DDC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes#Class_200_.E2.80.93_Religion

Comment: How *would* one start a proposal for an Other Religions stack?  Hypothetically, of course.

Comment: I don't see how experts in any of these "other religions" could possibly be attracted to such a site.  Instead, the most active users would end up being only the tiny cross-section of programmers (or other SE site users) who self-select to also answer questions about various religions.

Comment: @weakdna: [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/21960)

Answer (score 0):

As few comments noted, this could be valid question for [philosophy.stackexchange.com](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), just be careful with wording.

There is ethics tag:

> For questions about ethics, a branch of philosophy dealing with morality, justice, virtue, vice, good and evil.

I am sure morality (or even amorality) of love spells (or influencing in general) could be based on few presumptions and apply to many religions/world views.

Regarding to what @πάντα ῥεῖ said in comments: "but that also may need to have a serious scientific background regarding those love spells and if they work in the real world". This is not an issue, you can frame question as though experiment. Also depending on definition, love spells are real - you just need chemically/hormonally influence other person when with you.